# Different WindowSoftInputMode for activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, window-soft-input-mode

[image]I want to achieve the functionality shown in the image. Let me explain the scenario in details.

I have a main activity and several fragments. what I want is when the keyboard is open the activity will remain same (will not resize) but the fragment will change its height and will be shown above the keyboard.

I have tried to do this using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for activity and `getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);` in `onCreateView` of the fragment. But its not working properly. I am getting this.[image]

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: what does this mean - `not working properly`. Can you please tell issue.

Comment: thank you very much. I have edited my question. I hope this will explain things. Please check.